# read more / less for 2 different text

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with my code, i need to show 2 or more texts with read more and read less, but it words only on the first.
The second one works only, after i press 2 times on the button.

HTML CODE

```
            <h1 align="center">What is CSS?</h1>
            Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for describing 
            the presentation of a document written in a markup language.
            <div>
            <br>
            <span id="text">CSS is designed primarily to enable the separation of 
            document content from document presentation, including aspects such as the 
            layout, colors, and fonts..<br>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
            <button id="toggle">Read More</button>
            </div>

            <h1 align="center">What is CSS?</h1>
            Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for describing 
            the presentation of a document written in a markup language.
             <div>
             <br>
             <span id="text2">CSS is designed primarily to enable the separation of 
             document content from document presentation, including aspects such as the 
            layout, colors, and fonts..<br>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
            <button id="toggle2">Read More</button>
            </div>
```

JS CODE

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                  $("#toggle").click(function() {
                    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
                    if (elem == "Read More") {
                      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
                      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
                      $("#text").slideDown();
                    } else {
                      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
                      $("#toggle").text("Read More");
                      $("#text").slideUp();
                    }
                  });
                });

                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $("#toggle2").click(function() {
                    var elem = $("#toggle2").text();
                    if (elem == "Read More") {
                      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
                      $("#toggle2").text("Read Less");
                      $("#text2").slideDown();
                    } else {
                      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
                      $("#toggle2").text("Read More");
                      $("#text2").slideUp();
                    }
                  });
                });
```

CSS CODE

```
               #text{
               display:none;
               }
```

jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/nt_razvan/knogcm1d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second text is initially visible. You need to adjust your CSS.
Append this:

```
#text2{
    display:none;
}
```

or:

```
#text, #text2{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: damn...i totally forgot about the display none...thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the id

```
#text2{
display:none;
}
```

Take into account that in the beginning you are seeing the text number 2.

Reagrds,

Comment: Nevertheless I wouldn't use this solution, personally in the definition of the button I would call a js script function with the id of the element that is attached and then in the logic with only one function you can see if it is visible or not to know what to do.